# PDE problem with boundary values

Tags: partial-differential-equations

The PDE
$$ u_{xx}+ u_{yy}+\lambda u=0,0<x,y<1$$
$$ u(x,0)=u(x,1)=0, 0\leq x \leq 1$$

$$ u(0,y)=u(1,y)=0, 0\leq y \leq 1$$
has

(a) a unique solution $u$ for any $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$

(b) infinitely many solutions for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$

(c) a solution for countably many values of $\lambda $

(d) infinitely many solutions for all $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$

which are correct? I have absolutely no idea about this $\lambda$. Please help.

Comment: Separate variables and analyze the corresponding ODEs. You'll easily see when you can and cannot solve depending on $\lambda$

Comment: should I take $u= X(x)Y(y)$ and compute in the equation to move ahead?

Comment: Yes that's exactly right. Then you'll find that for $X,Y$ to satisfy the corresponding equations with the boundary conditions, $\lambda$ has to take certain values.

Comment: Assuming $u=XY$; I found $$\frac{X^{\prime \prime}}{X}+\frac{Y^{\prime \prime}}{Y}+\lambda =0$$ $$\frac{X^{\prime \prime}}{X}+\lambda = - \frac{Y^{\prime \prime}}{Y} = -k^2 (say)$$ which gave me a solution like $u=(c_1 \exp^{ky}+c_2 \exp^{-ky})(c_3cos \sqrt (\lambda + k^2)x + c_4sin \sqrt (\lambda + k^2)x ) $; what should I do now? on putting boundary conditions I arrive at a complicated result